# My Shiba goes for his toy after 30 seconds of petting

Tags: dogs, toys

my 10 year old shiba is a perfect angel at home.  Never chews on anything create messes.  However, every time I pet him he first wants to kiss me, then he starts getting a bit mouthy with your hand, but before he does anything he runs for his chew toy.  it's almost like "i am gonna bite you soon so i am getting up to chew on something else."

anyone with a similar experience?

Answer (score 3):

Our Labrador is the same.  He'll be ok with a few seconds petting and then he'll want to play with a toy or chew on a bone instead.

We just interpret it as a preference on being petted (he's perfectly happy to be petted while he's fully relaxed and dozy).

If you want to combine the biting and petting, I'd just offer a bone or NylaBone and hold it while he chews on it, it's a nice way of reinforcing the bond with you.

Answer (score 3):

Every dog has their own personality, just like every human has. Not every dog enjoys being petted to the same extend. For some, it's the best reward ever and could continue all day long, for others it's merely tolerated or outright loathed (especially when strangers try to pet them).

I think your dog feels that you want to reward him by social interaction, but that playing is the better reward for him. He communicates his preference by discontinueing the petting and offering a toy instead.